# Check if string have pair brackets closed with properly order

Tags: java

I want to make a function that check if a string have pairs brackets closed and if them are in order. For example:

- The String "[ ] [ ] [ ]" should return true
- The String "{ [ ( a b c ) ] }" should return true, also
- The String "{ [ [ } ] }" should return false, because

The brackets I want to check if have their pairs are "{", "}", "(", ")", "[", "]", "<", ">"

This is the code I have so far. **haveTheSameCount(String)** check if for each open bracket, exist their complement.
**fillBracketsPosition(List, String, String)** fill a list with the positions where each bracket appears in the code. I think I should check every position of the brackets in the string but I don't know what else I can do.

```
package Algorithms;

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class GetBracketPair {

  public static final String brackets_allowed[] = {"{","}","[","]","<",">","(",")"};

  public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    boolean r1 = haveEnclosedBrackets("abcde");
    boolean r2 = haveEnclosedBrackets("[]._.<>()");
    boolean r3 = haveEnclosedBrackets("{((})){}");
    //boolean r4 = haveEnclosedBrackets("{");
    System.out.println(r1);
    System.out.println(r2);
    System.out.println(r3);
    //System.out.println(r4);
  }


  // Given a certain string, the function have to ensure that contains a close bracket for every open bracket and should be in order
  // First, we will check if the counter for each element is equal in the String
  // Second, we will check if the order of each element is correct
  public static boolean haveEnclosedBrackets(String str) throws InterruptedException {
    boolean result = false;
    result = haveTheSameCount(str);
    return result;
  }

  public static boolean haveTheSameCount(String str) throws InterruptedException {
    int count_brackets[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    List <Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean result = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < brackets_allowed.length; i++) {
      count_brackets[i] = str.length() - str.replace(brackets_allowed[i], "").length();
    }
    if ((count_brackets[0] == count_brackets[1]) && (count_brackets[2] == count_brackets[3]) && (count_brackets[4] == count_brackets[5]) && (count_brackets[6] == count_brackets[7])) {
      result = true;
      list1 = fillBracketsPosition(list1,str,"{");
      if (list1 != null) {
        for (Integer i : list1) {
          System.out.println("Position of {: " + i);
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static List <Integer> fillBracketsPosition(List <Integer> positions, String str, String bracket) throws InterruptedException {
    int pos = -1;
    pos = str.indexOf(bracket);
    //System.out.println("First Pos: " + pos);
    if (pos != -1) {
      positions.add(pos);
      while (pos != -1) {
        pos = str.indexOf(bracket,pos+1);
        //System.out.println("Adding pos: " + pos);
        Thread.sleep(500);
        if (pos == -1) {
          return positions;
        }
        positions.add(pos);
      }
    }
    else {
      //System.out.println("bracket doesn't exist");
      positions = null;
    }
    return positions;
  }

}
```

Comment: Hmm, use a stack?

Comment: @TheLostMind could you please provide a more specific example about how could I use a stack for this case?

Comment: @MichaelBecerra check the dupe